Problems with react-leaflet in Next.js 15
I have a Next.js 14 app with react-leaflet that works fine. I wanted to update it to Next.js 15 but that caused some issues: In development mode the code return an unhandled runtime error "Error: Map container is already initialized." I guess this error is somehow related to double rendering in development mode but don't understand why it did not happenin next@14.2.16. I guess I can live with it because this works fine when I create a build and run it from there. But I am nevertheless curious about why this is happening.
The page.tsx code is as follows:
const Map = dynamic(() => import('./_components/map'), {
  loading: () => <p>The map is loading</p>,
  ssr: false,
});

The index.ts file in the _components/map folder does not incude a useEffect function and I have tried, wihtout success if I could somehow use useEffect to remove older instances of the Map container and initialize a new one only if there is none already initialized.


Please don't name variables the names of built-in classes. 2. According to the rules of React components must be idempotent, the double-rendering in dev mode is to flush out bugs exactly like this one. 3. "I have tried, wihtout success" please post your attempt, including how you're trying to render your map.


I have the same problem... Just migrating from nextjs14 ro nextjs15...  Any ideas ?

Thank you @JaredSmith. The relevant code in index.ts is as follows:
const Map = (Map: MapProps) => {
const {
zoom = defaults.zoom,
posix,
minZoom = defaults.minZoom,
maxBounds,
} = Map;
I found one example of a useEffect code that I tried here:
https://github.com/colbyfayock/next-leaflet-starter/blob/main/src/components/Map/DynamicMap.js
useEffect(() => {
(async function init() {
delete Leaflet.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl; ....
I tried also to get useEffect proposals from claude-3.5-sonnet without luck

I found that this has been discussed at
https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/1133
and that there is a rc version of react-leaflet available that solves this problem. I tried it ( react-leaflet@5.0.0-rc.1 ) and it worked!

I encountered the same issue.
Fixed by setting { reactStrictMode: false } in next.config
This a temporary workaround until it get fixed.

For god sake thank you I wasted a ton of time as i started new with nextjs and typescript so without any knowledge ... damn
